# Possible Symantec PIP OpenID provider bug?

Tags: support, bug, login, openid

I had previously been using myOpenID, but since they are not supporting it and SE is deprecating it, I figured I'd go ahead and change. So I tried to "add" my Symantec/Verisign PIP login to my SE account, and I got this error:

```
Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:

The OpenID Provider issued an assertion for an Identifier whose discovery information did not match. Assertion
endpoint info:
    ClaimedIdentifier: http://foo.pip.verisignlabs.com/
    ProviderLocalIdentifier: http://foo.pip.verisignlabs.com/
    ProviderEndpoint: https://pip.verisignlabs.com/server
    OpenID version: 2.0
    Service Type URIs: Discovered
endpoint info: [
  {
    ClaimedIdentifier: http://foo.pip.verisignlabs.com/
    ProviderLocalIdentifier: http://foo.pip.verisignlabs.com/
    ProviderEndpoint: http://pip.verisignlabs.com/server
    OpenID version: 2.0
    Service Type URIs: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/signon http://openid.net/sreg/1.0 http://openid.net/extensions/sreg/1.1 http://schemas.openid.net/pape/policies/2007/06/phishing-resistant http://schemas.openid.net/pape/policies/2007/06/multi-factor http://schemas.openid.net/pape/policies/2007/06/multi-factor-physical
  },
  {
    ClaimedIdentifier: http://foo.pip.verisignlabs.com/
    ProviderLocalIdentifier: http://foo.pip.verisignlabs.com/
    ProviderEndpoint: http://pip.verisignlabs.com/server
    OpenID version: 1.1
    Service Type URIs: http://openid.net/signon/1.1 http://openid.net/sreg/1.0 http://openid.net/extensions/sreg/1.1
  },
]
```

Is this because of the `ProviderEndpoint` being `https` in one case and `http` in the other? And if so, is there something I can do, or is that Symantec/Verisign's bug that they need to fix?

Comment: `foo` as a hostname. IT people are easily entertained. "Kettle? I'm mister Pot! You appear to be black. Just sayin..."

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I got your point...  but, I replaced my own ID with `foo` in `http[s]://foo.pip.verisignlabs.com/`. My actual ID is not `foo`. I did this for security/privacy considerations... although I suppose my ID is not / should not need to be private informaiton in order to maintain security. But nonetheless...

Comment: That was just a joke. :)